# 23.04 Lunar Lobster Dual Monitor Settings do not persist

Tags: multiple-monitors, hdmi, 23.04, vga, randr

Is there a way to reliably configure dual monitors in consistent positions that will always allow log in? One HDMI and one VGA monitor attached to a Lenovo T420 laptop constantly swap positions. Since upgrading to 23.04, they will not persist. Each log in, they switch, running arandr enables switching them back. They sometimes revert while working, but they always revert on login. A frequent error message indicates log in is not allowed due to the settings. Sometimes the login failure occurs multiple times. The laptop is always plugged in and never sleeps or power saves.

```
"HDMI-2", "DEL", "DELL 1704FPV", "H630453AA7B1"
"VGA-1", "VSC", "VA2037 SERIES", "TEQ130603821"
```

Comment: I'd check your cable connections are *firmly attached*, I've experienced this when a connection wasn't firmly attached (*and thus the OS was detecting removal of cable on movement momentarily, then re-attached which was seen as new monitor*), but being specific as to what you're using may help (ie. *is it Ubuntu 23.04 Desktop with default GNOME; my comment may not have based on GNOME for example though I use desktop features to change setup - not `randr`*)

Comment: lsb_release -a -> Ubuntu 23.04. gnome-shell --verision GNOME Shell 44.1. I use arandr because it is the desktop feature selected from Applications->SystemTools->Preferences that shows as Display Management. Cable connections are firmly screwed on.